# How to Navigate or visit an URL from Java code with HTTP headers

Tags: java

I am trying to navigate to a specific URL from my JAVA code. Like if I put "www.google.com", it must take me from my web application to the Google web site. I could have used  tag in the JSP itself, but I need to apped some information in the HTTP headers like login ID, as the navigating URL needs it.

So, how to navigate from my current URL to an external URL, by attaching some parameters to HTTP Headers in the request.

I really did some research, but could not find the answers.

I am currently using this code.

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

// add request header
request.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

But this code only sends the HTTP request, but does not actually navigate to that page. I want to redirect as well as pass some information in HTTP headers.

Comment: Have a look at : https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/index.html . There is a lot to read but this is a very fully featured HTTP library that may be useful ( if a little bit of overkill for what you are wanting to do )

Comment: You mean redirect? So that the next page that appears on your browser is a different web site? If so, you have no control of the headers the browser sends. The only way you can control the headers is if you proxy between them.

Comment: First, if you have information, especially code, please add it to your question by editing - don't use comments. Second, that's not redirection, that's actually getting the content of the URL on your server side. If that is what you wanted, then what is your question?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I have added some info to my question. I am actually trying to navigate to totally different website.

Comment: you have mentioned JSP here, so I assume you are using jsp/servlets ... you can create an action like <yourURL> and in your servlet/request handler you can redirect to whatever url you want...  search for "servlet url redirect" to see example..

Comment: @Sendi_t But you can't set headers in the request to a redirected URL.

Comment: @Sendi_t actually, I need to add some information to the HTTP header along with HTTP request while redirecting.